# Why do objects in Python list seem to be shallow copies of each other when created with default constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-constructor

Sorry for the bulky title, but I don't know how to best describe the kind of problem I'm encountering.

I define my own class and then create a list of objects with the default constructor (without passing any arguments). Later, when I want to access one of the objects in the list and call a function method, the properties of *all* list elements are changed at the same time and to the same values. It looks like all elements in the list are shallow copies.

Now if I create the objects by passing the default value explicitly as an argument, the list elements behave as expected and I can call the method on individual elements without changing the others.

This behavior is extremely puzzling and counterintuitive to me and I would like to understand why this happens.

A minimal example to reproduce the behavior looks as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
L = 10.

# define Particle object
class Particle(object):

    def __init__(self, position=np.array([0.,0.,0.]) ):
        self.position   = position

    def propagate(self):
        x = np.random.exponential(scale=L) # sample mean free path
        self.position  += np.array([x,0.,0.])

# initialize particle list
particles = 5
particle_list = []
for i in range(0, particles+1):
    p = Particle()                      # <- this does not work as expected!
    #p = Particle(np.array([0.,0.,0.])) # <- but this does!
    particle_list.append(p)

# testing
print("after creation")
print(particle_list[0].position)
print(particle_list[1].position)
print(particle_list[2].position)
print(particle_list[3].position)
print(particle_list[4].position)

particle_list[2].propagate()

print("after propagation of 1 particle")
print(particle_list[0].position)
print(particle_list[1].position)
print(particle_list[2].position)
print(particle_list[3].position)
print(particle_list[4].position)
```

The output in this case is

```
after creation
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
after propagation of 1 particle
[1.19354594 0.         0.        ]
[1.19354594 0.         0.        ]
[1.19354594 0.         0.        ]
[1.19354594 0.         0.        ]
[1.19354594 0.         0.        ]
```

even though the method has only be called on one element. Instead, if I change `Particle()` to `Particle(np.array([0.,0.,0.]))` the output becomes

```
after creation
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
after propagation of 1 particle
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
[7.55848724 0.         0.        ]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
```

which is what I want. Now I could be pragmatic and just accept this as a quirk of the language, but what do I do if an object does not have arguments I could pass to the constructor?

PS: I'm using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Oh wow, 14 seconds, this was fast. I was nearly sure that this question would already have an answer, but I was not sure what exactly to look for or how to better describe the problem. Thanks for pointing me to the answer!